# MapHub to specific route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I have a SignalR implementation which points to the default `/chat` route

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");
});
```

However, I would like to point to `/api/chat/`, but no matter what I've tried I couldn't find the right setting.
Would this be possible?

I've also tried specifying the `Route` attribute but without any luck:

```
[Route("api/chat")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, added these lines and it worked like a charm!

In starup.cs you have to use it in 'useEndpoints' instead of app.UseSignalR.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");
});
```

Here you could find source;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/signalr-usesignalr-useconnections-removed

Answer (score 0):

There is no such config for signalr hub like that if you want to custom your hub endpoint change in your code

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/somecustom-endpoint");
});
```

The way you config is the Route attribute for Web API which is not work you can remove it

Comment: I did see in the docs the `-` approach. I'll just keep it as `/chat`